# Admin input value is not accessible after adding the order increment ID while executing the command

Tags: magento2, orders, cli, sku, get

I created a custom CLI command where I have to delete the order Items using the Order Increment ID, Item SKU.

I used the ask() method after executing the command `php bin/magento webkul:orderDelete` when this command runs then it asks for the admin to add the increment ID:
After adding the integer ID I couldn't able to fetch what admin input in the terminal

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        $orderId = $input->getArgument(self::ORDER_ARGUMENT);
        $allowAll = $input->getOption(self::ALLOW_ALL);
        $orderAllColl = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();  //Get Order Collection
        foreach ($orderAllColl as $orderCollData) {
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderCollData->getEntityId());
            $orderIncrementId[] = $order->getIncrementId();                        //Delete Order
                }
                // echo print_r($matchId);
             $question = $objectManager->create('\Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion', ['question'=>'Please enter the Order Increament Id:', 'default' => FALSE]);
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        if(isset($helper)){
             $ans = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question);
             echo 'abc'.$ans;
        }
```

I am not able to get any data in the $ans variable after pressing Enter adding the increment ID of the order.

Can you please help me with how can I get the input value in the variable that I am accessing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $question = $this->_objectManager->create('\Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion', ['question'=>'your question', 'default' => FALSE]);
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        echo $ans = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question);
        if ($ans == 'yes') {
           $output->writeln('Hello World!');
        }else{
            $output->writeln('Noooooooo');
        }
        $output->writeln('Done!');
    }
```